# sql query a column and display all records with a count greater than

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to query a column and display all records with a count greater than 9 in the first player_id column.  Whenever a player in the first column plays any player greater than 9 times. The opponent can be anybody as long as it is greater than 9 times.

This is what I tried first.

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p2.player_id, 
     m.date, m.scoreA, m.scoreB, mem1.player, mem2.player, team1.name, team2.name
FROM matches m
LEFT
JOIN `members` mem1
  ON mem1.player      = m.playerA
 AND mem1.start_date <= m.date
 AND ( mem1.end_date >  m.date OR mem1.end_date IS NULL )
LEFT
JOIN `members` mem2
  ON mem2.player      = m.playerB
 AND mem2.start_date <= m.date
 AND ( mem2.end_date >  m.date OR mem2.end_date IS NULL )
JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB
JOIN teams team1 ON team1.team_id = mem1.team
JOIN teams team2 ON team2.team_id = mem2.team
where team2.name = "Prime" and team1.name = "FXOpen e-Sports Korea"
Group By p1.player_id
having count(p1.player_id) > 9
order by p1.player_id, p2.player_id, m.date;
```

This only gave two records. The two records with a count greater than 9. I want to see all records with a count greater than 9 in the first player_id column. Whenever a player in the first column plays any player greater than 9 times. The opponent can be anybody as long as it is greater than 9 times.

Then I tried this. I thought doing a query within a query would work.

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p2.player_id, 
     m.date, m.scoreA, m.scoreB, mem1.player, mem2.player, team1.name, team2.name
FROM matches m
LEFT
JOIN `members` mem1
  ON mem1.player      = m.playerA
 AND mem1.start_date <= m.date
 AND ( mem1.end_date >  m.date OR mem1.end_date IS NULL )
LEFT
JOIN `members` mem2
  ON mem2.player      = m.playerB
 AND mem2.start_date <= m.date
 AND ( mem2.end_date >  m.date OR mem2.end_date IS NULL )
JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB
JOIN teams team1 ON team1.team_id = mem1.team
JOIN teams team2 ON team2.team_id = mem2.team
where team2.name = "Prime" and team1.name = "FXOpen e-Sports Korea" and
p1.player_id in( select p1.player_id from players p1
                 Group By p1.player_id
                 having count(p1.player_id) > 9
               )
order by p1.player_id, p2.player_id, m.date;
```

This unfortunately just gave an empty set.

This is what my data looks like without the count.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------+
| player_id | player_id | date       | scoreA | scoreB | player | player | name                  | name  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------+
|         1 |         2 | 2012-01-18 |      1 |      0 |      1 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2011-08-22 |      1 |      3 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-01-02 |      1 |      2 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-01-18 |      0 |      1 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-06-22 |      2 |      1 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        47 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     47 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        49 | 2012-03-18 |      2 |      0 |      1 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        49 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        49 | 2013-05-28 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |       157 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |    157 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |       225 | 2011-08-12 |      2 |      0 |      1 |    225 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|        21 |         2 | 2013-06-03 |      2 |      1 |     21 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|        21 |        49 | 2013-06-03 |      3 |      1 |     21 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|        44 |         2 | 2012-01-18 |      0 |      1 |     44 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|        44 |         2 | 2012-03-18 |      1 |      2 |     44 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|        44 |         2 | 2012-11-09 |      0 |      1 |     44 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|        44 |         2 | 2013-06-05 |      0 |      1 |     44 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
```

Expected results

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------+
| player_id | player_id | date       | scoreA | scoreB | player | player | name                  | name  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------+
|         1 |         2 | 2012-01-18 |      1 |      0 |      1 |      2 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2011-08-22 |      1 |      3 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-01-02 |      1 |      2 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-01-18 |      0 |      1 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-06-22 |      2 |      1 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        14 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     14 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        47 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     47 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        49 | 2012-03-18 |      2 |      0 |      1 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        49 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |        49 | 2013-05-28 |      1 |      0 |      1 |     49 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |       157 | 2012-11-09 |      1 |      0 |      1 |    157 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
|         1 |       225 | 2011-08-12 |      2 |      0 |      1 |    225 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea | Prime |
```

Players table

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| player_id | tag       | real_name       | nationality | birthday   | game_race |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|         1 | Leenock   | Dong Nyoung Lee | KR          | 1995-04-01 | Z         |
|         2 | Creator   | Hyun Woo Jang   | KR          | 1996-08-19 | P         |
|         3 | Life      | Seung Hyun Lee  | KR          | 1997-01-11 | Z         |
|         4 | DongRaeGu | Soo Ho Park     | KR          | 1991-06-03 | Z         |
|         5 | PartinG   | Lee Sak Won     | KR          | 1994-08-24 | P         |
|         6 | TaeJa     | Young Suh Yoon  | KR          | 1995-01-01 | T         |
|         7 | Rain      | Yoon Jong Jung  | KR          | 1992-08-14 | P         |
|         8 | viOLet    | Dong Hwan Kim   | KR          | 1990-12-05 | Z         |
|         9 | Sniper    | Tae Hoon Kwon   | KR          | 1995-01-22 | Z         |
|        10 | Stephano  | Ilyes Satouri   | FR          | 1993-03-12 | Z         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Matches table

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| match_id | date       | tournament | playerA | playerB | scoreA | scoreB | offline |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
|        1 | 2012-12-04 |        799 |       4 |      55 |      1 |      3 |       0 |
|        2 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |       2 |      41 |      2 |      0 |       0 |
|        3 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      21 |      41 |      0 |      2 |       0 |
|        4 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |       3 |       2 |      2 |      1 |       0 |
|        5 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      41 |       2 |      1 |      2 |       0 |
|        6 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      21 |       3 |      1 |      2 |       0 |
|        7 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      1 |       1 |
|        8 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      3 |       1 |
|        9 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       8 |      19 |      3 |      2 |       1 |
|       10 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |      19 |      12 |      2 |      1 |       1 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Members table

```
+--------+------+------------+------------+
| player | team | start_date | end_date   |
+--------+------+------------+------------+
|      1 |   88 | 2011-02-23 | 2011-07-18 |
|      1 |    4 | 2011-07-18 | NULL       |
|      2 |    3 | 2011-01-12 | NULL       |
|      3 |   65 | 2010-10-19 | 2012-07-13 |
|      3 |    1 | 2012-07-13 | NULL       |
|      4 |    7 | 2011-02-20 | NULL       |
|      5 |   88 | 2010-10-29 | 2011-07-18 |
|      5 |    1 | 2012-10-21 | 2013-01-03 |
|      5 |   12 | 2013-01-14 | NULL       |
|      6 |   65 | 2011-03-01 | 2011-05-01 |
+--------+------+------------+------------+
```

Teams table

```
+---------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
| team_id | name                          | founded    | disbanded  |
+---------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | StarTale                      | 2010-09-15 | NULL       |
|       2 | Incredible Miracle            | 2010-10-01 | NULL       |
|       3 | Prime                         | 2010-10-13 | NULL       |
|       4 | FXOpen e-Sports Korea         | 2011-07-18 | NULL       |
|       5 | FXOpen e-Sports Europe        | 2012-03-03 | 2013-04-09 |
|       6 | FXOpen e-Sports North America | 2012-10-28 | 2013-08-07 |
|       7 | MVP                           | 2011-02-20 | NULL       |
|       8 | New Star HoSeo                | 2011-02-26 | 2013-07-31 |
|       9 | CJ Entus                      | 2000-05-09 | NULL       |
|      10 | KT Rolster                    | 2000-04-04 | NULL       |
+---------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You make your life MORE complex by having a table design with PlayerA & PlayerB. You also need to provide a few rows of data from each table with these questions (do this without being asked each time). Rows from a query that isn't working don't really help a great deal. But the "expected result" does help a lot.

Comment: @Used_By_Already The purpose of the table is to compare PlayerA to PlayerB. I don't know how to do this any other way.

Comment: I did show you how to "unpivot" that table and once it is unpivoted you only need one join to players and one join to members. But more importantly for this question: **What is the count of?** is it the number of times 2 teams have played against each other? or the same pair of players that have played each other? please "define" what the count is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I have two reasons for not using your unpivot method. I am having trouble understanding it so I am having trouble manipulating it. The second after I get the count right I need to compare ScoreA to ScoreB which will be more difficult with them being in their own record.

Comment: **What is the count of?** is it the number of times 2 teams have played against each other? or the same pair of players that have played each other? please "define" what the count is trying to achieve

Comment: @Used_By_Already Count greater than 9 in the first player_id column. Whenever a player in the first column plays any player greater than 9 times. The opponent can be anybody as long as it is greater than 9 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count greater than 9 in the first playerA column, using `inner join` and subquery

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p1.real_name, p2.player_id, p2.real_name, 
     m.scoreA, m.scoreB, mem1.player, mem2.player
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN (
    select playerA
    from matches
    group by playerA
    having count(*) > 9
    ) c9 on m.playerA = c9.playerA
JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
JOIN members mem1 ON mem1.player = p1.player_id
JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB
JOIN members mem2 ON mem2.player = p2.player_id
;
```

OR using `IN()` and subquery

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p1.real_name, p2.player_id, p2.real_name, 
     m.scoreA, m.scoreB, mem1.player, mem2.player
FROM matches m
JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
JOIN members mem1 ON mem1.player = p1.player_id
JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB
JOIN members mem2 ON mem2.player = p2.player_id
WHERE m.playerA IN (
    select playerA
    from matches
    group by playerA
    having count(*) > 9
    )
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience in figuring this out.